# Linq-to-Dataset Syntax: How to select specific fields correctly from a query and use them

Tags: linq-to-sql

When I say simply say "select c", the following code works, but I want to select the id, first name and last name, not the entire row as it is fairly lengthy.

I am fairly new to Linq. I had this working with anonymous types, but have been instructed to define all variables (hence all the as "IEnumeralbe(of DataRow)"'s)..but none of the examples I have come across use "Select" the way I want to and they don't tend to go on with the for loop using the fields selected in the query.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

---

```
    Dim cands As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = ds.Tables("Candidates").AsEnumerable()
    Dim candPlace As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = ds.Tables("JobCandPlacement").AsEnumerable()
    Dim candComp As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = ds.Tables(dctSearchCriteria.Values(i).ToString).AsEnumerable()
    Dim strCandID As String = ""

    Dim candMatches As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = From c In cands, cc In candComp, cp In candPlace
                Where c.Field(Of String)("candidateID") = cc.Field(Of String)("candID") _
                AndAlso cc.Field(Of String)("compSkill") = cSkill _
              Select c("candidateID"), c("firstName"), c("lastName")

   For Each cm As DataRow In candMatches 
        strCandID = ""
        strCandID = cm("candidateID") 
        increaseCandScore(strCandID)
        If Not dtSuitableCands.Rows.Contains(strCandID) Then
            Dim dr As DataRow = dtSuitableCands.NewRow
            dr("candID") = cm("candidateID")
            dr("candFName") = cm("firstName")
            dr("candLName") = cm("lastName")
            AddNewRow(dr)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `Option Infer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point.  The entire table is already in memory, so all you'll be doing is *adding* overhead.
LINQ never copies values, so the only way to optimize this is to get rid of the columns completely.

To answer the question, you need to select an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx):

```
Select New With { .ID = c("candidateID"), ... }
```

You can also use your current syntax, which is equivalent to this.

Since you're creating an anonymous type, you cannot declare it as `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)`; you must use `Option Infer` and write `Dim candMatches = From ...`

Comment: Thanks heaps! I think I need to go do more research on Linq to properly get the hang of it.